# How to fix Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Update::index(),

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Update extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!isLoggedIn()){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        $this->updateModel = $this->model('Update_model');
        $this->userModel = $this->model('User');

    }


    public function index($id){
        $user = $this->userModel->getUserById($id);

        $data = [
            'user' => $user,
            'desc' => 'Here You can edit or delete Your personal information'
        ];

        $this->view('update/index', $data);
    }
```

}

I'm trying to get **only one** user from SQL and type it in html view, but I accept this problem.
I tried to get all users form database, and i succeed, it's ok, but can't get only one user.

And here is my method to get one user

```
 public function getUserById($id){

    $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

    $row = $this->db->single();

    return $row;
}
```

When I delete $id from function index(**$id**), i receive another error
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\crudmvc\app\controllers\Update.php on line 16

Comment: Show the code relevant to the error.

Comment: Look at the prototype of `Update::index()` and then at your call. If the number of parameters dont match fix the call to use the required number of parameters, and of the correct type

Comment: @JonStirling here is my code, thanks

Comment: I don't see the code here that calls the `index` method.

Comment: I am guessing that `index()` is called by one of your Routes. But probably you are not defining the router to contain an `id` value

Comment: It's contoller that requires an Id. The route you defined (somewhere) for that controller doesn't have an "id" placeholder and thus is not passing it to `index()`.

Comment: In fact rather than trying to reuse `index()` you should define another route so you run `getById($id)` when an id is passed from the form

Comment: Thanks to everyone

Comment: I can't find the way to star you or give reiting up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted $id argument inside index() and assigned $id as

```
public function index()
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $user = $this->userModel->getUserById($id);

        $data = [
            'user' => $user,
            'desc' => 'Here You can edit or delete Your personal information'
        ];

        $this->view('update/index', $data);
    }
```